# Cannot convert string map to json

Tags: json, go, hash, redis, redigo

I'd like to make a json out of a hash received from redis using [redigo](https://github.com/gomodule/redigo):

```
func showHashtags(c *gin.Context) {
    hashMap, err := redis.StringMap(conn.Do("HGETALL", MyDict))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }    
    fmt.Println(hashMap) //works fine and shows the map 

    m := make(map[string]string)
    for k, v := range hashMap {
        m[k] = v
    }

    jmap, _ := json.Marshal(m)
    c.JSON(200, jmap)
}
```

However the result in browser is gibberish like:

```
"eyIgIjoiMiIsIjExX9iq24zYsSAiOiIxIiwiQWxsNFJhbWluICI6IjEiLCJCSUhFICI6IjMiLCJCVFNBUk1ZICI6IjIiLCJDTUJZTiAiOiIxI....
```

What is wrong here? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The variable `jmap` is type `[]byte`. The call to JSON encoder in `c.JSON()` marshals `[]byte` as a base64 encoded string as you see in the output.

To fix the problem, use one level of JSON encoding by passing the map directly to c.JSON:

```
hashMap, err := redis.StringMap(conn.Do("HGETALL", MyDict))
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}    
m := make(map[string]string)
for k, v := range hashMap {
    m[k] = v
}

c.JSON(200, m)
```

Because `hashMap` is a `map[string]string`, you can use it directly:

```
hashMap, err := redis.StringMap(conn.Do("HGETALL", MyDict))
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}    
c.JSON(200, hashMap)
```

Comment: Actually  `c.JSON(200, hashMap)` also gives gibberish in the browser. It is worth mentioning that the dictionary are of Arabic words.

Comment: The presence of Arabic words will not produce gibberish.  What does `fmt.Printf("%#v\n", hashMap)` print?

Comment: Well, I realized I needed to convert the Marshaled json to string before sending it to browser: `s := string(jmap)` and then `c.JSON(200, s)`